# How to change shells in script

Tags: bash, shell, csh

The default shell on the the system is `csh` but I want to write a script in `bash`. How do I write a script that will run bash and then convert back to csh at the end.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
bash
var=Hello
echo $var
csh
```

Comment: With a DOS .bat file, you might have needed to worry about switching back (though I'm not sure that the concept applies properly even there).  With Unix, you do not have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change shells back again.  When the script is run, it will be run by a sub-shell (which exits at the end of the script), and the parent shell is unchanged.  So, as already suggested, the only thing you have to do is ensure the script is run by the correct shell, and the 'shebang' is the way to do that:

```
#!/bin/bash
var=Hello
echo $var
```

That's all it takes.

Comment: I tried the same but if I run the script with sudo, it takes back the original shell

Comment: @mohitsharma — I'm not clear what you did and what went wrong.  You should probably ask it as a separate question, though.

Answer (score 3):

The command you are looking for is `exit`.  When typing at the keyboard use `exit`  instead of `csh` to get back to *csh*. When you entered`csh`, that just started a new *csh* session on top of the *csh* and *bash* sessions already running.

```
%bash
$ var=Hello
$ echo $var
Hello
$ exit
exit
%
```

As others have said, when using a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
var=Hello
echo $var
exit # You don't need exit; but it's okay here.
```

Answer (score 2):

Define it using the sha bang

```
#!/bin/bash
```

at the starting of your file.

Comment: To convert back to csh at the end, I would then use `#!/bin/csh` ?

Comment: No, at the end of the execution your script will return to the default shell, in your case csh.